# Why does changing font size with an event through javascript require closures?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, closures

I've been reading the mozdev article on closures and it has [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vnkuZ/) fiddle example:

```
function makeSizer(size) {
  return function() {
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
  };
}
```

the idea is to call makeSizer with a size, from an on-click event and it changes the font size. But if you cut out the nameless function and just do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vnkuZ/2783/):

```
function makeSizer(size) {
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
}
```

the clickable links stop having any effect and font size goes directly to the largest, as if the size16 link was clicked and the links don't have an on-click event anymore. Adding `return` doesn't change the behaviour.

(if it's unclear what I'm talking about, click the links above the examples, they have the fiddles)

My question is, why does this need closures/callbacks? Shouldn't a simple statement work? If it's about making a call to a function, why doesn't it work after the script loads? I get why it would default to the last size, since the function call now directly alters the size (and size16 is called last), instead of waiting for the call, but still, why doesn't it work after the page loads?

Comment: both of your fiddle links point to the same place

Comment: whoops sorry, fixing it now - edit: fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To answer your question:** Changing the font-size does not require closures.

**Now to why removing the inner function does not work:**

`makeSizer` is not the event handler. It is a function that creates functions and returns them. These functions are the event handlers. Let's break it down a bit:

```
var size12 = makeSizer(12);
document.getElementById("size-12").onclick = size12;
```

The first line executes the function `makeSizer` with *12* as a parameter. It creates another nameless function that sets the body's font-size to 12 and returns it. That means, that the variable `size12` now holds the function that has been created by `makeSizer`. `size12` does **not** hold the function `makeSizer` itself.

In the second line you assign `size12` to the onclick-Event of the clickable element. So the event handler for this event is now the function that sets the font-size to 12. It does **not** execute the function `makeSizer`!

If you change the function `makeSizer` so that there is no inner function anymore, it does not return anything, hence the variable `size12` is "empty". Then, when you assign `size12` the the onclick-Event, you assign "nothing" to the onclick-Event. That is why nothing happens.

Comment: Great thanks - this one along with bhb's clarified it for me. I'm not experienced with event-based languages so it looked weird to me but I understand now that it's not the closure that does the trick, it's the fact that an actual function is assigned to the event, whereas without returning a function, the event handler is practically empty.

Comment: @IvyLynx Odd how the one answer (bhb) that is completely wrong helped you understand. Also, your last words lead me to understand that you may have gotten a slightly wrong idea. If you understand that this code works perfectly, then you got the right idea: `var changeTo12Px = function() { document.body.style.fontSize = '12px' }; document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = changeTo12Px;`

Comment: Well he stated that the event handler requires a function - that's really what clicked in my head. The example works because you assign a function to a variable and that variable to the event, thus making it the event handler. In essence, it requires a function object. The example that didn't work wasn't returning a function, hence the issue. I think I got it fine :P

Answer (score 2):

What is happening without the callback is that the size is being set in quick succession to 12 then 14 then 16 as the script loads.

The callback is needed because you are defining what will happen when the link is clicked.

To understand the version with `makeSizer`, you should first understand the following version, which should do the same thing:

```
var setSize12 = function() {  document.body.style.fontSize = '12px'; };
var setSize14 = function() {  document.body.style.fontSize = '14px'; };
var setSize16 = function() {  document.body.style.fontSize = '16px'; };

document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = setSize12;
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = setSize14;
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = setSize16;
```

Comment: This one seems obvious, as you're linking the variables to the function text, like you're giving them a name. But why doesn't this: `function makeSizer(size) {
    return document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
}`

`var size12 = makeSizer(12);` work just as well? is it because makeSizer already has a name? edit - ofcourse, i'm only asking about _after_ the page has loaded and size12 is linked to a user event.

Comment: @IvyLynx `var size12 = makeSizer(12)` assigns `12px` to `...fontSize` and returns `12px` to the `size12` variable. What you want in the `size12` variable is a function that the browser can call when some element gets clicked.

Comment: Yeah it's obvious now - I think I was thinking of the code more in terms of C pointers rather than evaluations, which confused the hell out of me.

Answer (score 1):

The value you assign to `onclick` needs to be a function that will get called by the browser with the click event as an argument.
You want your function to be called with the size parameter. That won't work.

The solution is to find a way to bind the size into the function passed to the onclick and for that you use closures.

If you look closely at the mozdev code, you will see that as onclick handler they assign a function that doesn't expect any parameters:

`function(){ document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px'; }`

That function does indeed use the `size` variable, but it is not defined in its scope. Instead, they create a closure over the function where the size variable is defined. To this closure they pass the parameter that you wish to give:

```
function makeSizer(size) {
  // size is defined here, because it is a parameter
  return function() {
    // same size is here
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
  };
}
```

The return value of `makeSizer('12px')` is the function above that changes fontSize with no parameters and the size variable bound to `'12px'`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `onclick` event requires a function. So when you just return `document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';`, it doesn't get executed.

Comment: it is still wrong. Returning `document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px'` still assigns the value to fontSize, so it has effect/is executed. Take a look at the other answers that explain quite clearly the problems.

Answer (score 0):

In the non-working example, as soon as you define the variable

```
var size12 = makeSizer(12);
```

you are calling `makeSizer(12)` which executes the function and changes the size.

By contrast, on the working example, when you define the variable

```
var size12 = makeSizer(12);
```

you are creating a function (that's what `makeSixer()` returns in this case) with the parameter `12` but since you're just returning the function you aren't executing it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your toggling the font size on the click event you need to assign a function to act as the event handler when the click event is performed.

In the code example, the functions are stored into variables, being assigned the return value of the `makeSizer` function.

```
var size12 = makeSizer(12);
var size14 = makeSizer(14);
var size16 = makeSizer(16);
```

This requires `makeSizer` to retain the value of the supplied argument so it can be referenced when the event is actually fired.  Closures are a mechanism used to retain the scope of an outer function when calling an inner function.  In this case that inner function is stored in the variables you have declared and which are called `onclick` of each respective anchor tag.  Those closures contain the `size` argument supplied when the function was declared thanks to the closure.

Honestly, I think this is just a poor example.  If I were setting the font-size via Javascript, I would simply use an anonymous function:

```
document.getElementById("something").onclick = function(){
   document.body.style.fontSize = '16px';
};
```

or with the function:

```
document.getElementById("something").onclick = function(){
   makeSizer(12);
};
```