# closures in javascript understanding

Tags: javascript

[this is link from js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnkuZ/)

there is some js code there  like this:

```
function makeSizer(size) {
  return function() {
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
  };
}

var size12 = makeSizer(12);
var size14 = makeSizer(14);
var size16 = makeSizer(16);

document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = size12;
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = size14;
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = size16;  document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = size16;
```

and i have two questions the first one:
what is the profit of using this extra varibles

```
var size12 = makeSizer(12);
var size14 = makeSizer(14);
var size16 = makeSizer(16);
```

when you can just write

```
document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = makeSizer(12)
```

And the second one is: 
why when we write our function like this:

```
function makeSizer(size) {  document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';  }
```

everything stops working. I know that this is a duplicate and there some posts about closures but they don't help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doubts About Use of Practical Closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348255/doubts-about-use-of-practical-closure) or [Why does changing font size with an event through javascript require closures?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134072/solved-why-does-changing-font-size-with-an-event-through-javascript-require-cl)

Comment: i would to use `<a data-size="NN" class="sizer">` and single onclick handler on parent element using bubble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question:

It does not give you any profit in this example, but if you would like to use these functions as other onclick handlers that would save some resource and code would be easier to maintain.

Second question:

That's because first makeSize function returns function, which then is bind to click handler - this returned function is called each time click is made. 
Your changed function does not return anything (undefined to be more specific) so nothink is bind to onclick event.

Comment: Of course it gives a profit in the example – the (outer) function has to be run only once, instead of on every call.

Comment: @CBroe: Those variables `sizeN` don't.

Comment: Writing `document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = makeSizer(12);` would run makeSizer(12) only once, not on every click. Returned function would be run on every click.

Comment: Yes, but if you want to assign the same event to multiple elements, using `.onclick = size12` would run the outer function only once, whereas `.onclick = makeSizer(12)` would run it each time you assign an event handler this way.

Comment: @xaoonipu why just once?

Comment: That's what I wrote :) _but if you would like to use these functions as other onclick handlers that would save some resource_ only this size16 is called two times - but it looks like some mistake

Comment: @user2114177 because when you write funcName(params) - it calls this function and returns something. When you write funcName - without brackets you pass the reference of function. In your case makeSizer(12) when run - returns reference to function - which then is click handler.

Answer (score 0):

The `onclick` property requires a function that is executed when the event occurs.

The function will recieve a mouse event as argument. However in your case, the function needs to know the size that the font should be set to.

This is solved by creating the function on the fly and using closures to capture the size.

Comment: Don't even speak of strings that are `eval`uated… some people will get into mischief.